# How to fix vim color scheme in other terminals?

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, gnome-terminal

The problem I'm dealing with right now is I don't like gnome-terminal. I've tried alacritty, konsole, st (currently in use), and they're all having the same issue – they break my vim color scheme. Here's what I mean by that: [image: example] In this screenshot, gnome-terminal is on the left, and st is on the right.

I'm using **the same color profile** in both terminal emulators, and I don't have `.vimrc` since I rarely use vim locally. Somehow gnome-terminal manages to maintain the right colors, although in both terminals vim color scheme in use is the default one.

I've tried searching for ways to solve this, the only thing that I found is to specify the `$TERM` variable to be `xterm-256color`, but it didn't help. Another thing that I've noticed is when I force gnome-terminal's vim to use the default color scheme with `:colorscheme default`, colors are the same as in st's vim.

Recently figured out that the closest to gnome-terminal's default color scheme is `ron`.

I'm actually lost and have no idea what to do with this. There's no point in editing `.vimrc` because I ssh a lot and it won't have any effect. It doesn't sound like a big problem, but these colors are quite distracting. Any help will be appreciated, thanks to everyone who has read this.

Some command outputs:

-- gnome-terminal:

```
:colorscheme
default

echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

-- st:

```
:colorscheme
default

echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: terminals with colour support rendered the same theme differently, even when their `TERM` was the same (Xfce Terminal and Windows Terminal). I fixed it with:

```
set termguicolors
```

which tells VIM to use 24-bit colours. Since you don't use an RC file, you could alias the command somewhat like this.

```
alias vim='vim -c "colorscheme default" -c "set termguicolors"'
```

To preserve my aliases when I SSH into another system, I personally use [this](https://superuser.com/a/503785).

> ```
> function s() {
>   scp ~/.bashrc $1:/tmp/.bashrc_temp
>   ssh -t $1 "bash --rcfile /tmp/.bashrc_temp ; rm /tmp/.bashrc_temp"
> }
> ```

(I suppose one could simply copy `.vimrc` the same way.)